# Handle request.body timeout exception

Tags: python, django, heroku

I use `request.body` to get AJAX request data from jQuery to my django app, but sometime `request.body` cause a Dyno timeout, i guess it's because of the user droping the connection and django keep waiting for the user's request, the exception look like this:

```
File "/app/myapp/views.py", line 271, in proccess_api
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 233, in body
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 292, in read
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 51, in read
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 45, in _read_limited
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.60.0.46/newrelic/api/web_transaction.py", line 780, in read
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/http/body.py", line 212, in read
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/http/body.py", line 128, in read
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/http/unreader.py", line 38, in read
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/http/unreader.py", line 65, in chunk
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 176, in handle_abort
```

The line in proccess_api:

```
req_data = json.loads(request.body)
```

I'm using Django 1.8.11 on Heroku, the exception is recorded using newrelic.

My questions are:

- How to handle this exception?
- Is it possible to set a timeout for `request.body` so the request won't block the gunicorn worker?

Comment: How are you running gunicorn? Please also show your `wsgi.py` file.

Comment: What do you see in logs? 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits#http-timeouts

Comment: Please add your view code

Comment: @matagus `wsgi.py` is the default one that you get with `dango-admin startproject`

Comment: Please post the wsgi.py and the view code as well as what you see in the heroku logs. We can't help you you don't provide details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It look like this is a [design limitation in gunicorn](http://blog.etianen.com/blog/2014/01/19/gunicorn-heroku-django/):

> #### Gunicorn is designed to be used behind a buffering reverse proxy
>
> Gunicorn uses a pre-forking process model by default. This means that
>   network requests are handed off to a pool of worker processes, and
>   that these worker processes take care of reading and writing the
>   entire HTTP request to the client. If the client has a fast network
>   connection, the entire request/response cycle takes a fraction of a
>   second. However, if the client is slow (or deliberately misbehaving),
>   the request can take much longer to complete.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have much info from you, but based on what you posted...

*"How to handle this exception?"*
Wrap `req_data = json.loads(request.body)` in a `try`/`except` like so:

```
try:
    req_data = json.loads(request.body)
except:
    # Handle how you like
    # Maybe return a response 404 or 500?
```

It's even better if you can tell `except` what particular exceptions to look out for:

```
try:
    req_data = json.loads(request.body)
except ValueError:
    # Handle value errors
except TypeError:
    # Handle type errors
```

Hard to say more without the full error output (all the stuff after `File ...`) telling us what exact error Python threw. More about error handling [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html).

*"Is it possible to set a timeout for `request.body` so the request won't block the gunicorn worker?"*

I think this isn't a timeout problem. Clearly the URL linked to that view is getting some sort of `request` and tries to read its `body`. Based on the error output you gave us, `read` in the `request` module is what throws the error. *That's* why your code is stopping. The fact that the `request` body is unreadable means you should wrap it in a `try`/`except` as mentioned above.

Also, an adjustment that my help you is: `req_data = json.loads(request.body.read())`.

Comment: try/catch won't be helpful here, because the `request.body` will block the worker for the 30 seconds heroku allow (or wahtever worker timeout), the worker will be terminated. reading the source of `http/request.py`, `request.body.read()` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Aren't you using `request.body` to get the JSON-encoded body of the request? Wouldn't it make sense, then, to use `request.body.read()`? If you want more help you need to post the full error output and your view code. The AJAX request would also help. Otherwise people are just taking shots in the dark. Also don't downvote answers that don't make sense to you when you were the one who didn't post a complete question in the first place.